# Modify make file from g++ to use Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, makefile, g++

I am trying to use a **Makefile** which is supposed to run in windows environment. (It is SVM torch). The source website tells "You should only have to change the following lines, depending on your specific platform " (verbatim copy)

Being a newbie in Vis. Studio C++ I am not sure what should I write in place of these g++ in this code:

```
 # C-compiler  
 CC=g++ 
 #CC=CC 
 # C-Compiler flags  
 CFLAGS=-Wall -W -O9 -funroll-all-loops -finline -ffast-math 
 #CFLAGS=-native -fast -xO5 
 # linker  
 LD=g++ 
 #LD=CC 
 # linker flags  
 LFLAGS=-Wall -W -O9 -funroll-all-loops -finline -ffast-math 
 #LFLAGS=-native -fast -xO5 
 # libraries  LIBS=-lm
```

I am using Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

I understand I need to tell which compiler to use, but have not found the right *word* to replace g++

FYI:
1. I am typing: `nmake -f Makefile`

As expected in windows, I am getting the following error:

```
"'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'g++' : return code '0x1'
Stop."
```

2. Source is [this website](http://bengio.abracadoudou.com/SVMTorch.html)

Comment: Change `CC=g++` to `CC=cl`.  This will tell the makefile to use the Visual Studio Command line compiler.  Also change the `LD=` to use `cl`.  You may have to change the arguments as well.  Search the internet for "MSDN Visual Studio Command Line parameters".

Comment: Perhaps the make file is for a unix/linux make?  NMake is the make tool from windows.  Cygwin or Mingw come with a bash console that includes make.  Then I think you can change "CC=g++" to "CC=cl".  Not sure though.

Comment: There may also be a configuration utility that you need to run; this would create a `makefile` for Windows platform.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews :  changing 'g++'  -> 'cl' got the initial error clear. You are right the command line parameters need to get fixed. Checking for that.


The instructions that I got is to: unzip all, then modify the above lines according to platform, then run make.  I will look for configuration utility.

Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: @annoying_squid: the file has been modified to  work for windows. 

Initially, it was for Linux/Unix.\\\\**Thank you for your time and effort.**

New errors are parametric:
`cl : Command line error D8004 : '/W' requires an argument
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.`

Comment: Your `/W` requires an argument like it says.  A quick search brings up this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx .  Apparently you need to specify a warning level between 0-4.

Answer (score 0):

This `Makefile` was not intended to be used with the "native" Windows toolchain. You can not use `nmake` or a Windows version of `make`.

You can see this by looking at the `Makefile`, I copied a snippet:

```
37 clean:
38         rm -f *.o
39         rm -f SVMTorch
40         rm -f SVMTest
41         rm -f convert
```

`rm` is not a command in Windows so even if you used a Windows-version of `make` with the regular command prompt, this would fail.

Additionally, the code contains *nix-specific code. For example in `general.cc`:

```
33 long getRuntime(void)
34 {
35         struct tms buffer;
36         times(&buffer);
37         return((long)(buffer.tms_utime+buffer.tms_stime));
38 }
```

As far as I know, this type `struct tms` and function `times()` are not available on Windows and therefore will not compile if you use the MSVC compiler (`cl`).

All in all, you need to install something like [`mingw`](http://mingw.org/) that provides a Unix-like shell and a GNU compiler suite to build this in the regular way.

However, the `Makefile` is pretty simple, so I would give it a try to just create an MSVC project, add all source files to it and see what happens. Since the `Makefile` contains three executable targets, you will have to create three projects (at least) to make this work, but you could start with  building just one executable and see how far you get. You have to work around the *nix specific pieces of code though.

Answer (score 0):

**For make on Windows**

Using CXX and CXXFLAGS will do the trick. It will use cl.exe in place of g++ 
 Other thing to look for is using the **/** in file paths and using **-** for the cl.exe options when using the makefile.